# Ionic iOS Keyboard

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to display the iOS keyboard when a user click on a button.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="KbCtrl as ctrl">
    <button ng-click=(ctrl.showKeyboard())></button>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
angular.controller('KbCtrl', function() {
    var self = this;
    this.showKeyboard = function() {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
    }
})
```

So, when the user click on the button it will run the showKeyboard() function in my controller.
But nothing appears and I get this message on my system.log:

```
Showing keyboard not supported in iOS due to platform limitations.
```

How to fix this? I really need this functionality in my app.
Is there another way or maybe another plugin who works well on iOS??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Browser-API to focus an input element. This will automatically open the keyboard.

```
  var first = document.querySelectorAll('#myInputField')[0];
  if (first) {
    first.focus();
  }
```